# How to insert "count" and get "count" to JDBC DB Column?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jdbc, dao

I want to make a small "event apply page" for training.

*(the event is First-come, first-served basis.)*

I'm using JSP, JAVA(DAO(Data Access Object)) and oracle JDBC.

When a customer clicks "apply" button,

[1. id], [2. apply date], [3. apply count (+1)] will be saved in db table that I made.

I don't know how to make login session yet.
So I made input field that can input id directly when applying.

I can insert and get from db table about id and apply date.

But I'm trouble because *"apply" counting.*

I will put limit that no more apply when "apply count" is 100. (First-come, first-served basis)

How to insert apply count to DB and how to get count number from DB?

here is my code and situation.

**1. DB TABLE**

Column that I made are 3
[1. id] / [2. aug_cnt] / [3. applydate]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyuEX.png)

### **2. Applybean.java**

```
package model;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class ApplyBean {
    
    private String id ;
    private int aug_cnt;
    private Timestamp applydate;
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getAug_cnt() {
        return aug_cnt;
    }
    public void setAug_cnt(int aug_cnt) {
        this.aug_cnt = aug_cnt;
    }
    public Timestamp getApplydate() {
        return applydate;
    }
    public void setApplydate(Timestamp applydate) {
        this.applydate = applydate;
    }

}
```

**3. ApplyDAO.java**

```
public class ApplyDAO {     

    Connection con; 
    PreparedStatement pstmt; 
    ResultSet rs;   
    
    public void getCon() {          
        
        try {               
            Context initctx = new InitialContext();             
            Context envctx = (Context)initctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)envctx.lookup("jdbc/pool");
            con = ds.getConnection();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
    
    public void insertApply(ApplyBean abean) {

        try{    
            getCon();                       

            String sql = "insert into eventcount_aug values(?,sysdate)";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            pstmt.setString(1, abean.getId());
            pstmt.setTimestamp(2, abean.getApplydate()); 
            pstmt.executeUpdate();    

            con.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
}
```

I think I need to edit only "Applybean.java" file...

If I realize how to insert and get "apply count",

I can find how to make my event page perfectly.

I would be really grateful for your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you need following things:

1. Create sequence object in oracle:

> create sequence my_test_id_seq increment by 1;

2. Alter your Oracle table & use this sequence as default value:

> ```
>   alter table eventcount_aug modify (aug_cnt number default my_test_id_seq.nextval);
> ```

By this, you got capability that your aug_cnt column gets automatically incremented whenever there are inserts.

3. You can then use `select max(aug_cnt) as count from eventcount_aug;` before your insert call in `insertApply` which will decide if you need to go ahead with insert or not. For this you can create one utility method something like:

private int getCount(){

```
try{    
         getCon();                       
         int length=0;
         String sql = "select max(?) as count from eventcount_aug";
         PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

         pstmt.setString(1,"aug_cnt");
         ResultSet rs =  preparedStatement.executeQuery();    
       if (rs.next()) {
         length = rs.getInt(1);
       }
         con.close();
     }catch(Exception e){
    }
  return length;
```

}

And then use this in your `insertApply` before try block:

```
public void insertApply(ApplyBean abean) {
  if(getCount()<100){ // if count is less than 100, then only insert.
   try{
   ..
  }
```

---

Update : For oracle <12c versions , you can update your insert in your original `insertApply` method.:

```
String sql = "insert into eventcount_aug values(?,sysdate,my_test_id_seq.nextval)";
```

No need to re-create table or alter table & use sequence.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!

Could you answer my additional question??

If I want to add a query statement that you guide,
"select max(aug_cnt) as count from eventcount_aug;", 

where should i put it?? Should I create a new method?

Comment: ok, will update my original answer & give you suggestion, give me few mins; thanks

Comment: @doghot, done, ignore some of code formatting, as I am unable to use proper formatting, but this should work.

Comment: Thanks!! Sorry but I got error when I executed this query statement

"alter table eventcount_aug modify (aug_cnt number default my_test_id_seq.nextval);"
or "alter table eventcount_aug modify (aug_cnt int default my_test_id_seq.nextval);"



When I created table, I set datatype of aug_cnt "Integer".

What is wrong??

Comment: what is error ?

Comment: Error is **ORA-00984: column not allowed here**

FYI, "create sequence statement" was finished with no error.

Comment: which oracle version you are using?

Comment: Also, is this production code & is it possible for you to re-create table? Because my suggestion works on oracle 12c. If you have lower version of oracle, I will edit my answer & put how you can use sequence while creating table

Comment: I'm using oracle XE 11.2!

Comment: ohok, is it ok for you to re-create table?,

Comment: Sure I can re-create table!

Comment: just updated my answer, use create table like this & once table got re-created , test solution

Comment: I got error **ORA-00984: column not allowed here** When I create table..

`CREATE TABLE
           EVENTCOUNT_AUG
(ID VARCHAR2 (20) PRIMARY KEY,
 AUG_CNT INT DEFAULT MY_TEST_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
 APPLYDATE TIMESTAMP);`

What was wrong..?

Comment: Updated my answer @doghot, just ignore re-creating / alter table with sequence. it won't work with your oracle version. You can change your insert & use my suggestion

Comment: Thank you for your all answers and comments, I got errors after `pstmt.setString(1, abean.getId());` line..;;
 SQLException: Invalid column index.. I'll try and try until make it. Thx!!

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Oh.. I stayed up allnight but I didn't catch..
I put the debugging code at `insertApply' method like this

Comment: `public void insertApply(ApplyBean abean) {
  if(getCount()<100){ 
   try{
    getCon();   
    String sql = "insert into eventcount_aug values(?, sysdate, my_test_id_seq.nextval)";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1, abean.getId());  
    System.out.println("11111111111");
    pstmt.setTimestamp(2, abean.getApplydate());
    System.out.println("222222222222");  
    pstmt.executeUpdate
    System.out.println("33333333333");
    con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
       } 
                        }
}`

Comment: eclipse console returned only "11111111111"
and said `SQLException: Invalid column index`, `at model.MemberDAO.insertApply(MemberDAO.java:269)`

line 269 is `pstmt.setTimestamp(2, abean.getApplydate());`

Comment: You are using sysdate in insert & also using setTimestamp , my suggestion is to remove setTimestamp & see if it runs. Moreover, Make sure your order of insert is same as that of order of columns defined in table

Comment: Wow... Super thanks I removed pstmt.setTimestamp.. and it works.. 
but new problem occured. I put limit like this `if(getCount()<10)` (
I changed number to check codes.)
but application allow apply  11, 12, 13, 14, 15....:)

 I try to solve this problem. If you'd give me suggestion, I'll try for a few hours myself and come back and see.

Comment: @doghot, please check what is current sequence value & give it a try. it should work as getCount will return you max value of sequence. If it is not returning, try putting some sysouts in getCount() function & check value of sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't care about revocation of the application or concurrency problem. You can use another SQL to get the current count number before you insert a new application.

```
select max(aug_cnt) as count from eventcount_aug;
```

And then if count < 100 then set new count as count + 1, or else if count >= 100 then refuse the new application.